# how to pass control to next edittext in android on click of next keyboard key?

Tags: android

i have two text view  & two edittext view .....here is my xml

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="@string/email"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="@dimen/medium"
        app:font="font/trebuc_normal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_un"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_roundcorner"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        />

    <FontedTextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_pass"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/password"
        android:textColor="@color/gray"
        android:textSize="@dimen/medium"
        app:font="font/trebuc_normal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        style="@style/EditText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/edittext_roundcorner"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
         />
```

I want my control to pass to edit text with id password when user enters some text in email edit text view & presses enter.I have used imoptions but not working.After entering text when i press next button control goes to next line of same edit text view.Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set below Property of all Edittext, it will solve your problem.

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `editText.setNextFocusUpId(R.id.editText);`